# Powershell : sort xml by elements by child node value

Tags: xml, powershell

How to sort descending this xml by the second node of this list of "Tuple" (the "integer" typed) using Powershell.

So the result would be xml but the first element would be COMPUTERSF34, then COMPUTER123..

```
   <Result>
                <Tuple>
                    <Answer type="string">COMPUTERSF34</Answer>
                    <Answer type="integer">93</Answer>
                </Tuple>
                <Tuple>
                    <Answer type="string">NYCCOMPUTER01</Answer>
                    <Answer type="integer">44</Answer>
                </Tuple>
                <Tuple>
                    <Answer type="string">COMPUTER_05</Answer>
                    <Answer type="integer">45</Answer>
                </Tuple>
                <Tuple>
                    <Answer type="string">COMPUTER56</Answer>
                    <Answer type="integer">38</Answer>
                </Tuple>
                <Tuple>
                    <Answer type="string">COMPUTER123</Answer>
                    <Answer type="integer">51</Answer>
                </Tuple>
    ...
    </Result>
```

Comment: Why? Data-files shouldn't need to be sorted, that's what the application using it should do when reading it. AFAIK You'd need to group by the word(trim the numbers), then sort group members by the number(trim the word and cast to int) and sort the groups alphabetical.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
$xml = [xml]@'
   <Result>
                <Tuple>
                    <Answer type="string">COMPUTERSF34</Answer>
                    <Answer type="integer">93</Answer>
                </Tuple>
                <Tuple>
                    <Answer type="string">NYCCOMPUTER01</Answer>
                    <Answer type="integer">44</Answer>
                </Tuple>
                <Tuple>
                    <Answer type="string">COMPUTER_05</Answer>
                    <Answer type="integer">45</Answer>
                </Tuple>
                <Tuple>
                    <Answer type="string">COMPUTER56</Answer>
                    <Answer type="integer">38</Answer>
                </Tuple>
                <Tuple>
                    <Answer type="string">COMPUTER123</Answer>
                    <Answer type="integer">51</Answer>
                </Tuple>
    </Result>
'@
$sorted = $xml.Result.Tuple | sort {[int]$_.Answer[1].'#text'} -desc
$lastChild = $sorted[-1]
$sorted[0..($sorted.Length-2)] | Foreach {$xml.Result.InsertBefore($_,$lastChild)}
$xml.Save('c:\foo.xml')
```

The trick is to take each of the sorted nodes (except the last) and insert it before the new (post-sort) last node.